# C# script not completing a SQL Query before running the next step

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I have a c# script that is running as a part of a larger code. It's supposed to execute a sql script and then send the resultant .csv file through an SFTP connection.

The issue is that the query seems to be sending the data before the query is done executing. Is there a way to make sure the query is done before my program takes the next step?

Code for the SQL piece of this below.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SQLtoCSV
{
    static class SQL
    {
        public static DataTable GetData(string strQuery)
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            var strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RSConString"].ConnectionString;
            Logger.WriteLog("Used RS connection string: {0}", strConnString);
            var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            var sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RSTimeout"]);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.WriteLog("SQL GetData trown exception, see next entry.");
                Logger.WriteLog(ex);
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                sda.Dispose();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main control flow.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SQLtoCSV
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string sourceDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalSQLdirectory"].ToString();
                List<string> txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.sql", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

                Logger.WriteLog("Found {0} SQL files in local dir '{1}'.", txtFiles.Count, sourceDirectory);

                foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
                {
                    string strSql = File.ReadAllText(currentFile);
                    Logger.WriteLog("Executing '{0}'...", currentFile);
                    var dtTable = SQL.GetData(strSql);
                    Logger.WriteLog("Done.");
                    var tmpFile = currentFile + ".tmp";
                    TableToCSV.ConvertDtTableToCSV(dtTable, tmpFile);
                    var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentFile);
                    SFTP.upload(tmpFile, name);
                    File.Delete(tmpFile);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exception exMail = null;
                Logger.WriteLog("The main app trown exception, see next entry");
                try
                {
                    var msg = "CSV to SQL application thrown exception: \r\n" +
                              "\tSource: " + ex.Source + "\r\n" +
                              "\tMessage: " + ex.Message + "\r\n" +
                              "Stack: \r\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\r\n";
                    if (ex.InnerException != null)
                    {
                        msg += "Inner exception: \r\n" +
                               "\tSource: " + ex.InnerException.Source + "\r\n" +
                               "\tMessage: " + ex.InnerException.Message + "\r\n" +
                               "\tStack: " + ex.InnerException.StackTrace + "\r\n";
                    }
                    MailHelper.Send_Mail(msg, "SQL to CSV error");

                }
                catch(Exception ex2) {
                    exMail = ex2;
                }
                Logger.WriteLog(ex);
                if (exMail != null)
                {
                    Logger.WriteLog("Cannot send a mail, see next entry");
                    Logger.WriteLog(exMail);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TableToCSV section

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace SQLtoCSV
{
    static class TableToCSV
    {
        public static void ConvertDtTableToCSV(DataTable dt, string filePath)
        {
            string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);
                sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => /*string.Concat("\"", */field.ToString()/*.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\"")*/);
                    sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SFTP section

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Renci.SshNet;
using System.IO;

namespace SQLtoCSV
{
    static class SFTP
    {
        public static void upload(string tmpFile, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPhost"].ToString();
                var port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPport"]);
                var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPuser"].ToString();
                var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPpassword"].ToString();
                var workingdirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPdirectory"].ToString();
                var fileExtension = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadedFileExtension"].ToString();
                var timeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPtimeout"]);
                var timestamp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPtimestamp"].ToString();

                fileName += DateTime.Now.ToString(timestamp) + ".csv";

                using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
                {
                    client.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
                    client.Connect();
                    Logger.WriteLog("Connected to {0}", host);

                    client.ChangeDirectory(workingdirectory);
                    Logger.WriteLog("Changed directory to {0}", workingdirectory);

                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        Logger.WriteLog("Uploading {0} ({1:N0} bytes)", fileName, fileStream.Length);

                        // bypass Payload error large files
                        client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                        client.UploadFile(fileStream, fileName);
                    }
                }
                Logger.WriteLog("The file '{0}' is uploaded");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.WriteLog("The SFTP.upload function trown exception, see next entry");
                Logger.WriteLog(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static Stream StreamFromString(string s)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(s);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing that makes you say that the query is sending data before it is done executing? Is there more code where you can show what you are seeing exactly? For example, what line of code is the next step you mention?

Comment: where is the part of saving data? do you mean `sda.Fill(dt)` did not complete when `return dt` is done?

Comment: I'll post the main control flow into the original comment.

Comment: G_P. To clarify, I suspect the script is cutting off the temp file somehow. The data I get when I run the query manually is about 1gig; the files being sent through the script are about 20% of that. So either it's saving in a vastly more efficient format or not all the data is getting into the file.

Comment: Have you debugged it and checked the number of rows in dtTable when it is returned? I'm almost more inclined to say it is in your code to generate the csv than the SQL portion.

Comment: Where does `TableToCSV.ConvertDtTableToCSV` come from?  It seems like that might be the process that doesn't finish.  Is that `async`?

Comment: Matti, I am inclined to agree with you. A colleague of mine suggested a similar look. I am messing with it now and I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: As far as rowcounts are concerned. The TMP and the loaded CSV land at 1626890 but the same query manually run pulls up 1720942 rows. Nothing in the file is async that I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the CSV portion is your issue. `StreamWriter`'s are buffered by default so your last chunk of data isn't getting written to disk most likely. Add `sw.Flush();` before you end your `using` statement like this:

```
    public static void ConvertDtTableToCSV(DataTable dt, string filePath)
    {
        string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);
            sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => /*string.Concat("\"", */field.ToString()/*.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\"")*/);
                sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", fields));
            }
            sw.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sadly this gets me the same end result I was getting before with the file cut off. This might seem like a dumb question but could their be a limit on the tmp file-size that is preventing all the data from going in?

Comment: Oh wait, are you looking at the temp file or the FTP'd file for the line count you are seeing. What are you using to FTP the file?

Comment: I added the SFTP section so you can take a look. I don't think my theory on tmp file size could be correct since I can manually push to a .tmp and get the correct amount of data.

Comment: Well comment out that line that deletes your temp file and check it. Or set it to manually write it out somewhere else. Your FTP code is missing a `Flush` as well though.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say it, but the code itself was right although missing the flush sections. That said the issue turned out to be with a configuration file, causing the data to pull from a test environment as opposed to production.

Since the result sets from the two are often mirrored it was a subtle difference to find. I guess the moral of the story here is that if you are seeing really bizarre results that don't fit in with the theoretical picture of what you are seeing, it pays to step back a bit and make sure the basics are right.

Thanks to everyone that helped out!